# Move game screen diagonally using arrow keys

Tags: java, game-physics, arrow-keys

I'm creating a car game where it creates a **3D** pseudo **effect** by moving the **screen backwards and the car itself just stays still on the map**, using the arrow keys. It only takes in **one input at a time**, meaning you have to let go of an arrow key first. I have some code that I've got to show what I'm aiming for the screen to do as well, as the screen only moves forwards, backwards, left, and right.

Example of what I want the screen to do:

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7722803326073073681L;

private boolean left = false;
private boolean up = false;
private boolean down = false;
private boolean right = false;

public JLabel lbl = new JLabel ("mn");



public Main() {
    // Just setting up the window and objects
    setSize(400, 400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    lbl.setBounds(100, 100, 20, 20);
    add(lbl);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    // Key listener, will not move the JLabel, just set where to
    addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) left = false;
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) right = false;
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) up = false;
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) down = false;
        }
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) left = true;
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) right = true;
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) up = true;
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) down = true;
        }
    });

    // This thread will read the 4 variables left/right/up/down at every 30 milliseconds
    // It will check the combination of keys (left and up, right and down, just left, just up...) 
    // And move the label 3 pixels
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                while (true) {  
                    if (left && up) {
                        lbl.setBounds(lbl.getX() - 10, lbl.getY() - 10, 20, 20);
                    } else if (left && down) {
                        lbl.setBounds(lbl.getX() - 10, lbl.getY() + 10, 20, 20);
                    } else if (right && up) {
                        lbl.setBounds(lbl.getX() + 10, lbl.getY() - 10, 20, 20);
                    } else if (right && down) {
                        lbl.setBounds(lbl.getX() + 10, lbl.getY() + 10, 20, 20);
                    } else if (left) {
                        lbl.setBounds(lbl.getX() - 10, lbl.getY(), 20, 20);
                    } else if (up) {
                        lbl.setBounds(lbl.getX(), lbl.getY() - 10, 20, 20);
                    } else if (right) {
                        lbl.setBounds(lbl.getX() + 10, lbl.getY(), 20, 20);
                    } else if (down) {
                        lbl.setBounds(lbl.getX(), lbl.getY() + 10, 20, 20);
                    } 

                    Thread.sleep(30);
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
}
```

}

However, since the code above only moves the letters, I'm having a lot of difficulty in implementing it in the game as well. This is what I'm currently using to move the screen. (If I were to delete this method, nothing would appear).
What is currently happening:

```
public class RoadAppMain extends JFrame {

private static final int D_W = 1920; //Window dimension
private static final int D_H = 1280; //Window height
int grassWidth = 1920; //Width of grass
int vanishHeight = 768; // Height of vanishing point
int roadWidth = 900; //Width of the road
int rumbleLen = 800; //Length of each track stripe 
double camDist = 0.8; //Camera distance 
int N; //Size of each row or line
int playerPosX = 0; //Movement of player left and right
int playerPosY = 0; //Movement of player up and down

List<Line> lines = new ArrayList<RoadAppMain.Line>();

List<Integer> listValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();

DrawPanel drawPanel = new DrawPanel();

public RoadAppMain() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1600; i++) {
        Line line = new Line();
        line.z = i * rumbleLen;
        int curveAngle = (int) (Math.random() * 15 + 1);
        
        if (i > 20 && i < 70) { 
            line.curve = curveAngle;
        }
        
        else if (i > 100 && i < 150) {
            line.curve = -curveAngle;
        }
        
        else if (i > 180 && i < 230) {
            line.curve = curveAngle;
        }
        
        else if (i > 260 && i < 310) {
            line.curve = -curveAngle;
        }
        
        else if (i > 340 && i < 390) {
            line.curve = curveAngle;
        }
        
        else if (i > 400 && i < 420) {
            
        }
        
        lines.add(line);
        
    }
    
    N = lines.size();

    //Handles action events by user
    ActionListener listener = new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            drawPanel.repaint();

        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer(1, listener);
    timer.start();
    add(drawPanel);

    pack();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}

//Moves screen using arrow keys - THIS IS THE PART IM TALKING ABOUT
private class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

    public DrawPanel() {
        
        String VK_LEFT = "VK_LEFT";
        KeyStroke W = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0);
        InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW); //necessary
        inputMap.put(W, VK_LEFT);
        ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap(); //necessary
        actionMap.put(VK_LEFT, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                playerPosX -= 200;
                drawPanel.repaint();
            }
        });

        String VK_RIGHT = "VK_RIGHT";
        KeyStroke WVK_RIGHT = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0);
        inputMap.put(WVK_RIGHT, VK_RIGHT);
        actionMap.put(VK_RIGHT, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                playerPosX += 200;
                drawPanel.repaint();
            }
        });

        String VK_UP = "VK_UP";
        KeyStroke WVK_UP = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0);
        inputMap.put(WVK_UP, VK_UP);
        actionMap.put(VK_UP, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                playerPosY += 200;
                drawPanel.repaint();
            }
        });

        String VK_DOWN = "VK_DOWN";
        KeyStroke WVK_DOWN = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0);
        inputMap.put(WVK_DOWN, VK_DOWN);
        actionMap.put(VK_DOWN, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                playerPosY -= 200;
                drawPanel.repaint();

        }
        });
    }
        //Drawing components feature
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            drawValues(g);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 1920, 395);
        }

}

private void drawValues(Graphics g) {
    int startPos = playerPosY / rumbleLen;
    double x = 0; //Initial X position of screen on road
    double dx = 0; //Correlation between the angle of the road and player
    double maxY = vanishHeight;
    int camH = 1700 + (int) lines.get(startPos).y; //Height of the camera 
    //Starting position 
    for (int n = startPos; n < startPos + 300; n++) {
        Line l = lines.get(n % N); //Position of line
        l.project(playerPosX - (int) x, camH, playerPosY); 
        x += dx;
        dx += l.curve;
        if (l.Y > 0 && l.Y < maxY) {

            maxY = l.Y;

            Color grass = ((n / 2) % 2) == 0 ? new Color(21, 153, 71) : new Color(22, 102, 52); //Color for grass (first is for lighter, second for darker)
            Color rumble = ((n / 2) % 2) == 0 ? new Color(255, 255, 255) : new Color(222, 4, 4); // Color for rumble (first is white, second is red)
            Color road = new Color(54, 52, 52); // Color of road or asphalt
            Color midel =  ((n / 2) % 2) == 0 ? new Color(255, 255, 255) : new Color(54, 52, 52); //Color of hashed lines (first for white lines, second for gap)

            Color car = new Color(104, 104, 104);
            Color tire = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            Color stripe = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            Color light = new Color(253, 0, 0);
            Color hood = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            Color frame = new Color(0,0,255);
        
            
            Line p = null;

            if (n == 0) {
                p = l;
            } else {
                p = lines.get((n - 1) % N);
            }

            draw(g, grass, 0, (int) p.Y, grassWidth, 0, (int) l.Y, grassWidth); //(Graphics g, Color c, int x1, int y1, int w1, int x2, int y2, int w2)

            draw(g, rumble, (int) p.X, (int) p.Y, (int) (p.W * 2.03), (int) l.X, (int) l.Y, (int) (l.W * 2.03)); //Affects width of rumble
            
            draw(g, road, (int) p.X, (int) p.Y, (int) (p.W * 1.8), (int) l.X, (int) l.Y, (int) (l.W * 1.8));
            
            draw(g, midel, (int) p.X, (int) p.Y, (int) (p.W * 0.78), (int) l.X, (int) l.Y, (int) (l.W * 0.78)); //ADD HERE

            draw(g, road, (int) p.X, (int) p.Y, (int) (p.W * 0.7), (int) l.X, (int) l.Y, (int) (l.W* 0.7)); //To cover the gap in between each midel. Must be after to allow it to colour over it
            
            draw(g, car, 965, 927, 125, 965, 1005, 125);
            draw(g, tire, 875, 1005, 35, 875, 1050, 35);
            draw(g, tire, 1055, 1005, 35, 1055, 1050, 35);
            draw(g, stripe, 1050, 965, 30, 870, 980, 30);
            draw(g, stripe, 1050, 950, 30, 870, 965, 30);
            draw(g, hood, 965, 880, 90, 965, 927, 125);
            
            draw(g, light, 875, 950, 5, 875, 980, 5);
            draw(g, light, 890, 950, 5, 890, 980, 5);
            draw(g, light, 905, 950, 5, 905, 980, 5);
            draw(g, light, 1025, 950, 5, 1025, 980, 5);
            draw(g, light, 1040, 950, 5, 1040, 980, 5);
            draw(g, light, 1055, 950, 5, 1055, 980, 5);
            
            draw(g, frame, 965, 874, 86, 965, 880, 90);
            draw(g, light, 965, 874, 35, 965, 880, 45);
        
            }
        }
    
    }

    void draw(Graphics g, Color c, int x1, int y1, int w1, int x2, int y2, int w2) {

        Graphics g9d = g;
        int[] x9Points = { x1 - w1, x2 - w2, x2 + w2, x1 + w1 };
        int[] y9Points = { y1, y2, y2, y1 };
        int n9Points = 4;
        g9d.setColor(c);
        g9d.fillPolygon(x9Points, y9Points, n9Points);

    }
    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new RoadAppMain();
        }
    });
}

class Line {
    double x, y, z;
    double X, Y, W;
    double scale, curve;


    public Line() {
        curve = x = y = z = 0;
    }

    void project(int camX, int camY, int camZ) {
        scale = camDist / (z - camZ);
        X = (1 + scale * (x - camX)) * grassWidth / 2;
        Y = (1 - scale * (y - camY)) * vanishHeight / 2;
        W = scale * roadWidth * grassWidth / 2;
    }
}
```

}

How could I implement that movement into my game as well?